# LINQ Group By multiple table Inner Join and aggregate function

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, linq-to-entities, aggregate-functions

I have the following Linq to EF query:

```
from envelope in ENVELOPEs.AsNoTracking()
join spool in SPOOLs.AsNoTracking() on envelope.SPOOL_ID equals spool.SPOOL_ID
join extract in EXTRACTs.AsNoTracking() on spool.EXTRACT_ID equals extract.EXTRACT_ID
join extractProfile in EXTRACT_PROFILE.AsNoTracking() on extract.EXTRACT_PROFILE_ID equals extractProfile.EXTRACT_PROFILE_ID
join box in BOXes.AsNoTracking() on envelope.BOX_ID equals box.BOX_ID
join pallet in PALLETs.AsNoTracking() on box.PALLET_ID equals pallet.PALLET_ID
join fakeCap in FAKECAPs.AsNoTracking() on envelope.FAKECAP_ID equals fakeCap.FAKECAP_ID
join envWeightRange in ENVELOPE_WEIGHT_RANGE.AsNoTracking() on envelope.ENV_WEIGHT_RANGE_ID equals envWeightRange.ENV_WEIGHT_RANGE_ID
join ptype in PTYPEs.AsNoTracking() on spool.PTYPE_ID equals ptype.PTYPE_ID
join envType in ENVTYPEs.AsNoTracking() on ptype.ENVTYPE_ID equals envType.ENVTYPE_ID
join boxType in BOXTYPEs.AsNoTracking() on envType.BOXTYPE_ID equals boxType.BOXTYPE_ID
where spool.JSHEET_ID == 8
orderby envWeightRange.ENV_WEIGHT_RANGE_CODE,
    fakeCap.FAKECAP_DEST_TARIF
group new { envelope, envType } by
new 
{ 
    fakeCap.FAKECAP_DEST_TARIF,
    envWeightRange.ENV_WEIGHT_RANGE_CODE    
} into grouped
select new
{
    FAKECAP_DEST_TARIF = grouped.Key.FAKECAP_DEST_TARIF,
    ENV_WEIGHT_RANGE_CODE = grouped.Key.ENV_WEIGHT_RANGE_CODE,
    ENVTYPE_COD_OMOLOG = grouped.Max(item => item.ENVTYPE_COD_OMOLOG), // Error: ENVTYPE_COD_OMOLOG not defined
    TOTALE_BUSTE = grouped.Count()
}
```

It fails saying that filed ENVTYPE_COD_OMOLOG is not defined. (Sorry I would have wished to paste there the whole exception, but it's in not inenglish ue to OS locale settings).

However if I Include the field ENVTYPE_COD_OMOLOG in the group by without accessing it with aggregate functions, it works perfectly:

```
from envelope in ENVELOPEs.AsNoTracking()
join spool in SPOOLs.AsNoTracking() on envelope.SPOOL_ID equals spool.SPOOL_ID
join extract in EXTRACTs.AsNoTracking() on spool.EXTRACT_ID equals extract.EXTRACT_ID
join extractProfile in EXTRACT_PROFILE.AsNoTracking() on extract.EXTRACT_PROFILE_ID equals extractProfile.EXTRACT_PROFILE_ID
join box in BOXes.AsNoTracking() on envelope.BOX_ID equals box.BOX_ID
join pallet in PALLETs.AsNoTracking() on box.PALLET_ID equals pallet.PALLET_ID
join fakeCap in FAKECAPs.AsNoTracking() on envelope.FAKECAP_ID equals fakeCap.FAKECAP_ID
join envWeightRange in ENVELOPE_WEIGHT_RANGE.AsNoTracking() on envelope.ENV_WEIGHT_RANGE_ID equals envWeightRange.ENV_WEIGHT_RANGE_ID
join ptype in PTYPEs.AsNoTracking() on spool.PTYPE_ID equals ptype.PTYPE_ID
join envType in ENVTYPEs.AsNoTracking() on ptype.ENVTYPE_ID equals envType.ENVTYPE_ID
join boxType in BOXTYPEs.AsNoTracking() on envType.BOXTYPE_ID equals boxType.BOXTYPE_ID
where spool.JSHEET_ID == 8
orderby envWeightRange.ENV_WEIGHT_RANGE_CODE,
    fakeCap.FAKECAP_DEST_TARIF
group new { envelope, envType } by
new 
{ 
    fakeCap.FAKECAP_DEST_TARIF,
    envWeightRange.ENV_WEIGHT_RANGE_CODE,
    envType.ENVTYPE_COD_OMOLOG
} into grouped
select new
{
    FAKECAP_DEST_TARIF = grouped.Key.FAKECAP_DEST_TARIF,
    ENV_WEIGHT_RANGE_CODE = grouped.Key.ENV_WEIGHT_RANGE_CODE,
    ENVTYPE_COD_OMOLOG = grouped.Key.ENVTYPE_COD_OMOLOG,
    TOTALE_BUSTE = grouped.Count()
}
```

Comment: @Sankarann It's not, because i don't get why I cannot use aggregate functions as I should. In this way I am forced to include a lot of field in the group by Key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that query, `grouped` is an `IGrouping<TKey,T>` where:

- `T` is the projected type, in this case `new { envelope, envType }`
- `TKey` is the grouping key, in this case (without including `ENVTYPE_COD_OMOLOG` ):

  ```
  new { 
      fakeCap.FAKECAP_DEST_TARIF,
      envWeightRange.ENV_WEIGHT_RANGE_CODE
  }
  ```

An `IGrouping<TKey,T>`, apart from having a property `TKey Key` can also be viewed as an `IEnumerable<T>`. That means to get the max `ENVTYPE_COD_OMOLOG` from each group, you will need to change your select in the following way (The `Max` will apply over a sequence of `T`):

```
select new
{
    FAKECAP_DEST_TARIF = grouped.Key.FAKECAP_DEST_TARIF,
    ENV_WEIGHT_RANGE_CODE = grouped.Key.ENV_WEIGHT_RANGE_CODE,
    ENVTYPE_COD_OMOLOG = grouped.Max(item => item.envType.ENVTYPE_COD_OMOLOG),
    TOTALE_BUSTE = grouped.Count()
}
```

That way you don't need to group by `ENVTYPE_COD_OMOLOG` and can still get the maximum per group in the result.

Comment: Thank you very much. Both for the explanation and the solution.